# Installing Coot on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I would like to install the crystallographic program Coot on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, yet there only seem to exist 14.04 and 18.04 [versions](https://www2.mrc-lmb.cam.ac.uk/personal/pemsley/coot/). I tried installing the 18.04 version, but it started to complain about the missing libraries. What I did next, is just copied the libraries from the coot folder into /usr/lib but am now stuck with:

```
::: DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH is
/home/neitz/coot-Linux-x86_64-ubuntu-18.04.1-pre-release-gtk2-python/libexec/coot-bin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/neitz/coot-Linux-x86_64-ubuntu-18.04.1-pre-release-gtk2-python/libexec/coot-bin)
/home/neitz/coot-Linux-x86_64-ubuntu-18.04.1-pre-release-gtk2-python/libexec/coot-bin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/neitz/coot-Linux-x86_64-ubuntu-18.04.1-pre-release-gtk2-python/libexec/coot-bin)
Guile 1.8.8
Copyright (c) 1995, 1996, 1997, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008 Free Software Foundation
Guile may be distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public Licence;
certain other uses are permitted as well.  For details, see the file
`COPYING', which is included in the Guile distribution.
There is no warranty, to the extent permitted by law.
catching the crash log:
coot-exe: "/home/neitz/coot-Linux-x86_64-ubuntu-18.04.1-pre-release-gtk2-python/libexec/coot-bin"
/bin/ls
coot-version: 
/home/neitz/coot-Linux-x86_64-ubuntu-18.04.1-pre-release-gtk2-python/libexec/coot-bin
/home/neitz/coot-Linux-x86_64-ubuntu-18.04.1-pre-release-gtk2-python/libexec/coot-bin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/neitz/coot-Linux-x86_64-ubuntu-18.04.1-pre-release-gtk2-python/libexec/coot-bin)
/home/neitz/coot-Linux-x86_64-ubuntu-18.04.1-pre-release-gtk2-python/libexec/coot-bin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/neitz/coot-Linux-x86_64-ubuntu-18.04.1-pre-release-gtk2-python/libexec/coot-bin)
platform: 
/bin/uname
core: #f
No core file found.  No debugging
```

I have additionally tried running Coot from [Phenix](https://www.phenix-online.org/), but to no avail. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

I thank you kindly for all your help!

Comment: The version for 14.04 is more likely than that for 18.04 to work on 16.04 - `glibc` is generally *backward* compatible. Failing that, your options are to upgrade your system to 18.04, or to build Coot yourself from source.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

`sudo apt-get install -f`

You might have some dependencies fixed through that process. If not, please provide the log file of yours for additional troubleshooting.